# Create automatically property and assign value from column

Tags: c#

I`m building a model from this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/iris-clustering

I`m wondering if there is a better solution for this part of code, which would not require writing [LoadColumn(n)] every time as well as creating new properties.

```
public class IrisData
{
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public float SepalLength;

    [LoadColumn(1)]
    public float SepalWidth;

    [LoadColumn(2)]
    public float PetalLength;

    [LoadColumn(3)]
    public float PetalWidth;
}
```

I was thinking to replace the code above with something like:

```
IDictionary<int, float> irisData = new Dictionary<int, float>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        irisData.Add(i, [LoadColumn(i)])
    }
```

But it gives me a bunch of errors.
What is the best way to do it?

---

It seems easier that I thought. I ended up with this solution:

```
[LoadColumn(0, 3)]
[VectorType(4)]
public float[] iris_data { get; set; }
```

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming, the number of properties is not 4, but 400, it would be too hard type [LoadColumn(n) public float name_n; by hand

From this comment on another answer, don't forget; you're a software developer - you can code up a solution to the problem i.e. write some code that writes C# like some steing concat and fill down on excel or SQL that outputs 400 rows that are c# text  :)

Or you can use an already invented wheel. Sublime Text's a very powerful text editor with features that will handle this

If I had 400 public properties in a class and I wanted to put 400 attributes on, with an incrementing number in each I would

- ensure I had sublime with the test pastry plug-in installed
- paste my class in with 400 props
- double click the top `public` key on the prop
- hold down Ctrl-D on the keyboard (because I like taking a break) and watch sublime multiselect ervery one of 400 public words, giving me 400 cursors
- type `[LoadColumn(` on the keyboard, watch sublime type it 400 times for me
- call up the command palette window and find "text pastry 1 to X", also known as `\i`, run it. 1 to 400 appears in the document
- finish typing `)] <ENTER> public` to close the attribute and restore the public that was overwritten initially

---

Visual Studio can do the same if you have Multiple Carets Booster installed

- again select one `public`
- hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>></kbd> til they're all selected
- type `LoadColumn(1` so all the numbers are 1 then press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>LEFT_CURSOR</kbd> to select all the 1s
- press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to replace them with an incrementing sequence starting from 1
- finish `)] <ENTER> public`

---

You can also achieve the same in VSCode (it has multiple carets and text pastry)

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure what's wrong with `LoadColumn`? It's declarative purpose is very different from the code that you show as imperative alternative. By putting `LoadColumn(0)` you create `LoadColumnAttribute` that maps a field to column in your data file.

What are you trying to accomplish with the imperative code? You *could* use something like `new LoadColumnAttribute(i)` - but again the result is the attribute that mathches field to column; not the value in the column

Maybe explain what you want to do

Comment: Maybe my code is confusing, cause I am not familiar how LoadColumn works.  I am trying to find a solution rewrite the code above but be able automatically create properties. Assuming, the number of properties is not 4, but 400, it would be too hard type  [LoadColumn(n) public float name_n; by hand.